# wordpress multisite, how to keep user on subdomain throughout registration process?

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration

I am running wp subdomain multisite in combination with domain mapping. This means I can create a new subdomain site xyz.site.com and map the domain name 'xyz.com' to that site.

The problem I have is someone clicks 'register' on the subdomain mapped site 'xyz.com' and they are sent to site.com to register.

This is VERY confusing to many people and I'm getting tired of the complaints.

How do I setup wp multisite, so that if a person wants to register on a subdomain site, that they do not leave that site at any point?

*I use multisite to host multiple client sites, all which have their own domain names. I simply 'map' the domain name to their subdomain site. This means that users who come to one clients site to register, are being sent to the primary site to register, which is just plain wrong and confusing*

Comment: What is your setup? Are you using built in features to do this or plugins? Perhaps sharing some settings from you wp-config.php file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @petermolnar suggested also redirects your users to the main site if they want to register (I've tested this but feel free to make use of it. It's good practice).

What you need is a registration/login/edit-profile plugin for the front end:
http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1341-wordpress-profile-builder-a-front-end-user-registration-login-and-edit-profile-plugin/

It's shortcode based so all you have to do is redirect your users to the register page where you have [wppb_register] shortcode. Create register/login/edit-profile pages for each site you need and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option  in the network management for this. *Unfortunately my only available domain mapped network sites are in Hungarian, sorry if I don't use the exact name of the menu.*

Go to Network Administration -> Settings -> Domain mapping.

You'll see a checkbox titled "Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)", I think you're searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a two step solution for this problem :

1. Install a [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) and redirect the standard wp-signup.php page to your custom created page.
2. Create a custom registration page. Install the [Multisite User Registration Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-registration-manager/) and in the custom registration page include the shortcode for registration form [murm-form]

With this system all of your registration requests for your "subdomain or multidomain " website will be redirected to your custom regisration page. Now you will moderate only the user requests.