# Users are being redirected to main site when trying to register on subsite of my Multisite network

Tags: plugins, multisite, user-registration, signup

I want to allow my clients on my network to have visitors register on their site. Currently, there is no link or button to allow visitors to access the signup page. This looks like default functionality for some bizarre reason. Anyone trying to reach "subdomain.mydomain.com/wp-signup" is redirected to "mydomain.com."

Instead, visitors should be able to register on the subdomain, and remain there, without ever seeing my domain.

So far in my research, others have recommended Multisite User Management, however this did not do what I needed. I don't want any manual involvement in the user registration process of my clients.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

WP: 3.4.2

Comment: Have you seen answers to a similar question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/wordpress-multisite-how-to-keep-user-on-subdomain-throughout-registration-proce/)? My own solution was a small hack to wp-login.php!

Comment: Thanks Parham, I'm experimenting with the profile builder plugin now. It looks promising, but I already notice a few areas of improvement. For example, no enforcement on password length/complexity. Activation links leads to main site, not site which user registered on, etc. I hope I can hack my way through it. Thanks. I'm still open to other potential solutions.