# User registration problem on multisites web

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I'm using a multisite setting in my website. Where I had install WP on **something.web.com** where I have some content, menu, plugins atd. I set network admin with Domain Mapping and I have second domain with different name **anything.site.org** and if I click on **Register** at **anything.site.org**, I'm redirecting to **something.web.com/wp-signup.php** but I need **anything.site.org/wp-signup.php**.

My second problem is when user registred I want to add him into another multisite.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Note that WP multisite was designed to work like that - users have to register on the main site.  I have looked into whether users could register on a sub-site.  I could not find a way without modifying core, wp-signup.php; so I gave up on it.

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/wordpress-multisite-how-to-keep-user-on-subdomain-throughout-registration-proce?rq=1

Comment: can you post site url here ?

Comment: So, we will use login and reg with CAS system. Thx for your answers.